# NSSet SetByArray confused why I have an extra element - SKProductsRequest not working properly

Tags: ios, nsset, skpaymenttransaction

I have the following code..

```
 NSArray *productIdentifiersArray = [packs valueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(productIdentifier))];
 NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifiersArray];
```

Please see the image below... 
Why is there an extra element in the first slot of NSSet. I'm not really sure how to debug this but I know I need the NSSet for SKProductsRequest.

[image]

Comment: Looks correct, your array had loads of empty strings in it...

Comment: Those are free items without productIDs. Any ideas why I have exactly 1 empty string element instead of 10?

Comment: I see, because they are the same...

Comment: I wonder if that will cause a problem with code ----> `SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [self.injector getInstance:[SKProductsRequest class]
                                                           withArgs:productIdentifiers, nil];`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what you ask, trimming the duplicate objects from then array. It won't trim empty strings out though, they are entirely valid.

Ideally you wouldn't up the empty strings in the array in the first place, but worst case you can remove the empty string before you use it.

If you make the request with the empty string it will be an little slower and will return the empty string to you as an invalid identifier.

Comment: Thanks, true. My overall actual problem is the `NSArray *products` from SKProductsRequest is coming back with 0 products in the next slice of code. I doubt an empty string would cause this, right?

Comment: Ah ha!!! I found something at least... `for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers){NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId); }`

Comment: leads to this ...`Invalid product id: com.puteko.colarmix.unlock
2015-04-02 15:25:43.613 Quiver[242:5855] Invalid product id: com.puteko.colarmix.dover
2015-04-02 15:25:44.948 Quiver[242:5855] Invalid product id: com.puteko.colarmix.bdamanfireblast
2015-04-02 15:26:16.568 Quiver[242:5855] Invalid product id: com.puteko.colarmix.packaanz`

Comment: But that only happens 95% of the time...so now what?

Comment: Check the status of them in iTunesConnect. It should work or not, not fail only sometimes...